# How to use an image as cover with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to design a responsive website with Bootstrap 3 and CSS. For the cover I am using an image. It's dimensions are 4928 × 2747 (probably too large?).

Until now I was integrating it like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron cover">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <hr border-top="3px">
    <h1 class="cover">Heading</h1>
    <a class="btn btn-cover" href="#" role="button">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
      Check out the XX
    </a>
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron.cover {
  background-image: url('images/new/DSC_0750_cropped_blended.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 700px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Since thinking about the responsive-aspect, I figured that a fixed `height: 700px;` is not an option. But when I drop it, the image is cut at the bottom. I think the height of the cover-div now is defined by the sum of the heights of all elements in it.

Basically I am asking myself where and how to define the height of a div when trying to keep things responsive?

Comment: Are you looking for [`min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)?

Comment: "4928 × 2747 (probably too large?)." Depends...will this be displayed on a video wall? Otherwise...yes.

Comment: @George: `min-height` wouldn't work, as I would have to define a different value for each viewport size, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution below or you have to use media queries:

```
<div class="jumbotron cover">
  <img src="images/new/DSC_0750_cropped_blended.jpg">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <hr border-top="3px">
    <h1 class="cover">Heading</h1>
    <a class="btn btn-cover" href="#" role="button">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
      Check out the XX
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .jumbotron.cover {
    position: relative;
   }
  img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Could you explain your approach, please? I don't see where you set the size of the cover. Will give it a shot, though. Thanks.